# writing python list as row of text file

Tags: python

I have a python list as follows:

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I want to write it in text file as follows:

```
1,2,3,4,5 ##as comma delineated.
```

I tried as:

```
with open ('data.txt', 'w') as fo:
   for d in data:
     fo.write(str(d) + '\n')
```

But it wrote data as follows:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

How would you do it guys?

EDIT:

I will also have other lists obtained from for-loop, so all the one list i.e., 1,2,3,4,5 have to be adjusted in one line. In addition, I need faster performance.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `join` method

```
with open ('data.txt', 'w') as fo:
     fo.write(','.join(str(i) for i in data))
```

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you want a CSV (comma separated value) file as your output. You can use the [CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) python module.

An example could look like:

```
import csv

data = [1,2,3,4,5]

with open('test.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    writer.writerow(data)
```

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is to convert the list to a joined string, then write:

```
str_data = ','.join(str(i) for i in data)
with open('data.txt', 'w') as fo:
    fo.write(str_data)
```

In case if the list is too long to convert it all to the string:

```
with open('data.txt', 'w') as fo:
    for idx, item in enumerate(data):
        if idx:  # don't need a comma before the list
            fo.write(',')
        fo.write(item)
```

Update: that all said, aus_lacy's suggestion about CSV seems the best.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
with open ('data.txt', 'w') as fo:
    fo.write(','.join([str(n) for n in data]))
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way

```
data=[1,2,3,4,5]
with open ('data.txt', 'w') as fo:
   for d in data:
      if d!=data[len(data)-1]:
         fo.write(str(d)+',')
      else:
         fo.write(str(d))
```

Not so simple one:

```
dat=','.join([str(t) for t in data])
fo.write(dat)
```